# WPF: Sharing resources across assemblies

Tags: wpf, prism, resourcedictionary

I [previously posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422538/getting-a-componentresourcekey-to-work) on sharing resources across assemblies using `Themes/generic.xaml` and the `ComponentResourceKey` markup extension. The solution works nicely, but it requres all of the shared resources to be located in the `generic.xaml` resource dictionary. Mine is getting rather large, so I thought I would use merged dictionaries in `generic.xaml` to organize things.

I have had no luck so far. I ran some tests using the demo from my previous post, and as soon as I move resources to a merged dictionary, the `ComponentResourceKey` fails, complaining that it can't find the source file for the merged dictionary.

Has anyone else gotten this working? How? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [WPF Resource Dictionary in a separate assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338056/wpf-resource-dictionary-in-a-separate-assembly)

Comment: Thanks! The Pack URI approach ends up being simpler than using the ComponentResourceKey markup extension. I think I am going to switch to the PackURI approach.